# android "market place" hangs on start up

Tags: google-play-store, 2.3-gingerbread, updates

I have Samsung Galaxy s2. After setting up a Google account on my phone and using android market for first time, it shows a notification about removing "market place" application and replace it with "play store". (I live in Iran and Google does not allow me to use play store features). So, I bought a vpn account from Germany, connect to it and download and update to play store. Everything is okay.
After 3 months of using my phone, everything was fine. Last week I restored my phone and all data has been removed. And after setting up a Google account I tried to update market place to play store. But problem is, when I try to start market place, it hangs on start screen, and just show white screen with loader in center of display, after 20 seconds it closed and returned to home screen.
I tried to connect with vpn connection (I thought it's because of country restriction again, but recently my country changed the laws and closed any connections like pptp, l2tp, https, ipsec. Now I just connect with my real ip)
Any help, any comment, any way to update and connect to play store?